# What model contains Wilcoxon's rank sum test?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ranks

As Frank Harrel mentions in the answer to [Logistic regression and Wilcoxon test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10564/logistic-regression-and-wilcoxon-test),
Wilcoxon's rank sum test (aka Mann-Whithey test) is contained in the proportional odds logistic regression, which would e.g. allow to adjust the test results for potential confounding.

Now, on the other hand, the p value from a Wilcoxon rank sum test can be approximated by a two-sample t-test on the ranks, at least if the sample size is not too tiny. Since the t-test is contained in the normal linear model, this opens a different way to account for potential confounding effects.

Do you know any publication that investigates advantages of one or the other model in generalizing the Wilcoxon rank sum test? What is your recommendation?

A small example in R

```
set.seed(10)

n1 <- 20
yA <- runif(n1)
yB <- runif(n1) + 0.1
y <- c(yA, yB)
ttt <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = n1)

wilcox.test(y ~ ttt) # p-value = 0.0009334

# prop odds model
library(MASS)
summary(fit1 <- polr(factor(y) ~ ttt)) # t value 3.243

# rank reg
summary(fit2 <- lm(rank(y) ~ ttt)) # t value 3.708, p value 0.000665
```