# ANOVA is to ANCOVA as Kruskal–Wallis is to...?

Tags: regression, anova, inference, ancova, kruskal-wallis-test

ANCOVA is an ANOVA with an added covariate, and I find it quite elegant how both can be seen in a general regression framework.

If, however, I want to do a Kruskal–Wallis-type of test that accounts for some covariate, what would that be? That is, what kind of regression model(s) turn into the regular Kruskal–Wallis test if the covariate is ignored?

(If it helps, I am probably interested in two-sample comparisons, not the full $k$-sample comparison that ANOVA and KW do.)

Comment: Maybe some hints in an old, unanswered post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222553/what-model-contains-wilcoxons-rank-sum-test

Comment: @MichaelM So it would be a proportional odds model with the categorical variable and the covariate as the predictor? // I have had trouble getting Frank Harrell's `rms` package to give a proportional odds p-value equal to the p-value that I get from R's `wilcox.test`, even when I do a model with just the binary group variable as a predictor.